# Need help finding a phone number and a string using regular expressions

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and I an trying use regex to find **any** number of characters that comes after the question mark and before the pipe, along with the phone number. Can anyone please help me? Below is a sample URL ?

http://www.myurl.com?demo|15555555555

regular expression should find "demo" and "15555555555"

Comment: Thank you very much hjpotter92!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a regex with named capturing groups, also I tried to cover many possibilities for different number formats

**Regex**

```
(?<=\?)(?'name'[\w\s%]+)\|(?'phone'[\+\w-\(\)\s%]+)(?:\n|$)
```

**Test string**

```
http://www.myurl.com?demo|15555555555
http://www.myurl.com?Local|754-3010
http://www.myurl.com?Domestic|(541) 754-3010
http://www.myurl.com?International|+1-541-754-3010
http://www.myurl.com?Dialed in the US|1-541-754-3010
http://www.myurl.com?Dialed from Germany|001-541-754-3010
http://www.myurl.com?Dialed from France|191 541 754 3010
http://www.myurl.com?skype|155555-SKYPE
http://www.myurl.com?an%20escaped%20name|191%20541%20754%203010
```

**Result**

- MATCH 1

  - name [21-25] `demo`
  - phone    [26-37] `15555555555`
- MATCH 2

  - name [59-64] `Local`
  - phone    [65-73] `754-3010`
- MATCH 3

  - name [95-103]    `Domestic`
  - phone    [104-118]   `(541) 754-3010`
- MATCH 4

  - name [140-153]   `International`
  - phone    [154-169]   `+1-541-754-3010`
- MATCH 5

  - name [191-207]   `Dialed in the US`
  - phone    [208-222]   `1-541-754-3010`
- MATCH 6

  - name [244-263]   `Dialed from Germany`
  - phone    [264-280]   `001-541-754-3010`
- MATCH 7

  - name [302-320]   `Dialed from France`
  - phone    [321-337]   `191 541 754 3010`
- MATCH 8

  - name [359-364]   `skype`
  - phone    [365-377]   `155555-SKYPE`
- MATCH 9

  - name [444-463]   `an%20escaped%20name`
  - phone    [464-486]   `191%20541%20754%203010`

try [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/gD2pS0/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time  and giving a detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

if you create that link yourself, I would recommed you to write a common $GET-variable. you won't need any regex.

http://www.myurl.com?demo=15555555555

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["demo"]);
```

Comment: hahaha. That's the problem. I am using a 3rd party web services only takes one GET parameter. I am trying to look for a work around

Comment: as @hjpotter92 said: \?(\w+)\|(\d+)  

you can test regex expressions eg. here http://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\?(\w+)\|(\d+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/vS8cA9/1)**

[image]

```
MATCH 1
1.  [21-25] `demo`
2.  [26-37] `15555555555`
```